# how to fix emulator duplicate mac address?

Tags: mac-address

we're a company that sells android box that has an emulator installed on it, but we're facing a duplicate mac addresses problem, this problem occurred when we started using android boxes with 5g support on it, does this cause the problem ? the emulator we install is STB emulator

Answer (score 0):

It will cause problem if 2 devices are in the same local network. Even if it's not thought to be used like this your clients may want to try it and would be surprised if it doesn't work.

Tools exist to generate (via software) a random or different Mac address. `macchanger` for instance on Linux distributions.